# What is the ligthest possible valid icon?

Tags: optimization, icons

I aim to create the ligthest possible valid .ico file.
I have no idea where the limit is for a valid ico file.

Currently the best I could achieve is a 1x1 black .ico, which size 70 octets.
Can I do lighter? What should I do to have the lightest possible ico file?

Comment: How do you measure the weight of an icon?

Comment: @Armali. By right clicking on it > Properties, then reading its size.

Comment: An Icon file contains a number of images; if zero is a legal number (I don't know), a file with that number is the _lightest possible_.